# Anylogic - conveyor grab behaviour

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to merge 2 conveyors into 1 - See:

[image]

In the conveyor´s properties I can define the grab behaviour from the previous conveyor. 
Is there a possibility to define different grab behaviours for two different incoming conveyors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define different grab behavior for incoming conveyors in the properties of the Conveyor block. However, it is possible to change grab behavior dynamically when the incoming conveyor change. You can do it by using the function set_grabBehaviour() with one of the following arguments: Conveyor.GRAB_SMOOTHLY, Conveyor.GRAB_ON_AT_ENTER, Conveyor.GRAB_ON_FULL_ENTER.